# How to change value of firebase data, it databaseRef exist with valueEventListener in different class

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I have fragment with ratingBar. If use database reference here, data will change, but when i return and try enter again app crash, because in this moment is added only data about rating bar

I tried interface, but when i do that, fragment has:

> Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

```
//Fragment
override fun onRatingChanged(ratingBar: RatingBar?, rating: Float, fromUser: Boolean) {

        // val mDatabase: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads")
        //val itemReference = mDatabase.child(objectId)
        //itemReference.child("stars").setValue(rating.toDouble())
        setStars(rating.toDouble())
    }
```

```
//Activity
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads")

        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                mUploads.clear()
                for (postSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val upload: Upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload::class.java)!!
                    (mUploads).add(upload)
                }

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                mProgressCircle.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(this@ImagesActivity, databaseError.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                mProgressCircle.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        })

    }
//My interface try
    override fun modifyItemState(itemObjectId: String, stars: Double) {
        // val mDatabase: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads")
        val itemReference = mDatabaseRef.child(itemObjectId)
        itemReference.child("stars").setValue(stars)
    }
```

[it was change from 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o10bj.png)
[when i want back to this fragmentactivity, stars is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxwQe.png)

Comment: Please indicate what is the exact data that you want to change. Please add your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo In this case, only stars : double